# How to deactivate v2Signing of Unity3D gradle?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, signature, oculus

I'd like to deactivate signature V2 of gradle in Unity for uploading my apk file to Oculus dashboard.

Unity may build apk files according to *mainTemplate.gradle* and generates *build.gradle*.
I added following texts to *mainTemplate.gradle*.

```
signingConfigs {
  release {
    v1SigningEnabled true        
    v2SigningEnabled false
  }
}
```

Unity builder, however, activates signature V2 during building and overrides signing settings.
*build.gradle* shows signature V2 activation (Please see an attached image).

[Left:mainTemplate.gradle, Right:build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbDbp.png)

How do I edit the signature settings?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for replying. 
Finally I re-sign my apk file with apksigner.

```
apksigner sign --ks <keystore> --ks-key-alias <alias name> --v2-signing-enabled false  --v3-signing-enabled false --out <output name> <re-signed apk file>
```

Comment: where did you run this command? Inside Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Oculus Folder.
Click on the settings file just inside.
Look at the Inspector, make sure GO/GearVR is checked.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a commented line at the top of the mainTemplate.gradle that needs to be removed before it will actually use the mainTemplate.gradle changes

Someone else suggests doing it like this if that is not the issue, and it potentially could be an ordering issue.

```
**SIGN**
  // Add this block just below **SIGN**
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      v1SigningEnabled true
      v2SigningEnabled false
    }
  }
```

Source: https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/73099/apk-is-signed-with-signature-scheme-v3

Might also want to try removing `**SIGN**` and `**SIGN_CONFIG**` if they exist and manually set those values in the file instead of using Unity and see if it starts using your changes

Alternatively, I have used jarsigner (or the replacement, apksigner) externally after creating a build alongside zipalign, which is not as optimal as editing the gradle is, but allows for editing the build with scripts using APKtool if needed. The APK should not signed with a release key at all in Unity. Doing so before doing this may cause the APK to not be installable. There is a more in depth video of this in the link provided above.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner